# Record user's voice and save it to db in Django

Tags: django, database, postgresql, forms, recorder

I want to build a Django app in which a user can record his/her voice. I have used the following link: https://github.com/Stephino/stephino.github.io/blob/master/tutorials/B3wWIsNHPk4/index.html
in order to capture user's voice and it works perfectly for me, but I do not know exactly how to save it to database. I do not know how to build my Model and also a form to do this. Does anybody have any idea? (The obligatory framework is Django and in terms of db my preference is Postgresql)

Comment: This link's page is not found. Can you help me with the code anyhow?
that will be great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think storing an audio file in a Database is not a feasible solution.
You should consider using Django FileField Instead.

Refer to the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

```
# file will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/2021/05/27
upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and I agree with you that it is not a feasible solution. But I don't know how to pass the path of file stored in MEDIA_ROOT to the db. Because in the provided link the actual voice recorded in the front-side is an audio tag with  a blob source. I don't know how to save this to MEDIA_ROOT in my Django app.

Comment: You need to add an AJAX request and send the file to the server using input type File and regarding the media root, you only need to define it to the settings file.  Django will do the rest for you.